# Samesite cookie warning issue in chrome browser console window when submitting PayPal form on body load

Tags: google-chrome, paypal, google-chrome-devtools, document, samesite

When running our ASP.net application using a chrome browser that submits a PayPal form on body load at run time, a warning message "**A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://paypal.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with 'SameSite=None' and 'Secure'**" is getting appeared in Google chrome browser console window.

The following PayPal form is basically built at run time via code and it is getting submitted. As the form gets submitted, the cookie warning message is getting displayed and then getting navigated to PayPal website

```
<html>
  <body onload='document.forms["paypalForm"].submit()'>
    <form id="paypalForm" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
      <input></input>
      <input></input>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried setting the target framework of my project to "**.Net Framework 4.7.2**" to make use of "**SameSite**" attribute in the code and made code changes to fix the cookie warning issue. Even after making several changes in the code, i am still getting the warning message in Google chrome browser console window

Can you please let me know the solution in order to fix the Samesite cookie warning message?

Answer (score 0):

This message is displayed by Chrome due to things happening on the PayPal website.

It has nothing to do with your website, your code, or your implementation.

It is something for PayPal to worry about. You should ignore it.

Comment: The warning message is getting occurred immediately when a PayPal form is submitted from our application code. It is getting disappeared when it gets redirected to PayPal website for further processing. I believe that the issue needs to be fixed in our application itself in order to handle the cookie warning issue.

Comment: No, nothing to do with your application.